# Android studio 3.0 Canary 4 does not recognize AndroidManifest.xml in different flavor

Tags: android-studio

I have a project setup with 2 different flavours.

Each has flavour has its own androidmanifest.xml and there is also a main androidmanifest.xml

I use android studio 2.3.3 to develop my app, and everything was working fine.

But when I used android studio 3.0 canary 4, it seems that it couldn't find a "default activity".

When I tried to move the SplashActivity declaration from one the flavour version of androidManifest to main androidManifest. It works again.

Is there anyway for me to not have to move things around? If I move the declaration, the build process for the other flavour will fail because I'd have to declare two default activity.